# React findOne returning undefined on Client

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I'm having problems using findOne because it always returns undefined.

This code:

**Routine.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
    .... // Some lines missing
    'routines.getRoutine'(routineId) {
        check(routineId, String);
        return Routines.findOne(routineId);
      },
});
```

Note: If I do a console.log of Routines.findOne(routineId) it correctly shows the element that i'm looking for.

**App.jsx**

```
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const comment = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.comment).value.trim();
    Meteor.call('routines.addComment', this.state.routine._id, comment);
    let a = Meteor.call('routines.getRoutine', this.state.routine._id);
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.comment).value = '';
    this.setState({
      routine: a,
    });
  }
```

In my Appjs doesn't matter how I try 'a' is always undefined, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Looks like the Meteor.call is not returning a value synchronously or you are not allowing the state to update via the `routines.addComment`.  You can try adding a timeout after the addComment to see if it is defined after the state change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your problem is that Meteor calls on the client are async and so the method you're calling hasn't completed by the time you're querying the same data.

Try putting the rest of the code in the callback like so:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const comment = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.comment).value.trim();
    Meteor.call('routines.addComment', this.state.routine._id, comment, function() {
        let a = Meteor.call('routines.getRoutine', this.state.routine._id);
        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.comment).value = '';
        this.setState({
            routine: a,
        });
    });
}
```